# Reply to with text messaging

Tags: coldfusion

Is there a way to send a text message to someone and in the message have a single button/link that will send a text message from their phone to a voting mechanism?

Example: Pedro is running for class president.  I want to send a text to everyone that says:

```
Vote for Pedro!
```

And when they click on the link, it sends a text message from their phone to 73774 with the text: 110084.

I'm asking this in the ColdFusion section because I know ColdFusion and don't know PHP.

Comment: Pretty sure the answer is no. You could say "Reply to this text message with the word 'pedro' to vote for him!"

Answer (score 0):

No, text messages are just that... text.

Now, if you send a link, such as http://vote.for/pedro, most phones will automatically highlight that and open it in the users browser, but this isn't quite what you are looking for.